# how to check if bookmarks exist in html document

Tags: php, html

I've just designed my first form in HTML and a PHP page to display the results. In the form the user inputs some codes in response to some questions, a bit like a multiple choice, so for example, these are "ABC". The PHP page displays the code to the user as a link, which when clicked will go to a bookmark (a link within the same page) with the ID #ABC. This was achieved with simple manipulation of the PHP variable as follows:

```
<?php
$code = "ABC"
$part1 = '<a href="mywebpage.php#';
$part2 = '">Go to this code</a>';
$string = $part1.$code.$part2;
echo $string;
?>
```

(i.e. Link in the page says "go to this code" and when clicked will go to section with bookmark ABC)

This all works fine, but I simply need to know if there is a way of error trapping so that if a bookmark does not exist for the code entered, a message can be displayed to the user instead? Can this be done using the PHP variable, or do I need to use JavaScript? One work around may be to search the web page for the ID "#ABC'. Is it possible to do this? Another option would be to store an array of valid codes on the server then query this before setting the bookmark, but I want to keep it as simple as possible. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: unless php has a copy of the page that's being displayed to the user, this cannot be done. php runs on the server, the page is displayed on the client, and php cannot "query" the client to see what's available. you'd need JS code on the client to report back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

What you call a "bookmark" we call a hash. And when you say "go to a bookmark" you mean a hash change. Hash changes do not make an additional request to the server, it is all handled on the client-side, therefore this must be done with JavaScript and not PHP.

So let's just do some simple JavaScript on hash change [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) that will search for an element with that ID and if it's not found alert something.

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
  if(!document.getElementById(location.hash){
    alert("not found");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dustin and Marc. I have now used JS instead. It was easy to declare an array containing all the possible codes, and then use an If Else statement to query whether the code was in the array or not and then generate the bookmark.

Comment: If you have an array instead of using an `else` just do `if(array.indexOf(location.hash)==-1)`, this will be faster